# POSTGRESQL: referencing a column of table in another database

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, schema

I have two separated databases in my server. I would like to use tables from one database in the other one, so I have created a foreign schema:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgres_fdw;
CREATE SERVER core_server
  FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
  OPTIONS (host 'localhost', dbname 'core_db');
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR CURRENT_USER
  SERVER core_server
  OPTIONS (user 'root', password 'mysupersecretpassword');
CREATE SCHEMA core;

IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA public
  FROM SERVER core_server
  INTO core;

CREATE USER MAPPING FOR root
  SERVER core_server
  OPTIONS (user 'root', password 'mysupersecretpassword');

GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA core TO root ;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA core TO root;
```

Now I can access any table of the core server in my database. For example, I have a 'user' table in the core server, so I can access its content with the following code:

```
SELECT * from core.user;
```

It works properly.

Now I would like to create a table in the database that references a column in the user table (of the 'core' schema). I'm trying to achieve this with the following sentence:

```
CREATE TABLE localtablename ( id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, user_id INT REFERENCES core.user (id) NOT NULL);
```

But I get the following error message:

```
ERROR:  referenced relation "user" is not a table
```

I've tried with core.user, "core"."user" and other combinations, but I always get this error. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You can not create foreign key constraints to foreign tables. Only "local" tables are supported. If you need that, you have to put everything into a single database and use schemas to separate your tables (which also removes the need to use a foreign data wrapper)

Comment: Also, "user" is a teriible name for a table.